# How to select an item conditionally in a ForEach element?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI I want to show the favourite items only and I'm trying to do this with an if statement within the ForEach-element. See the code:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                Text("Favorites only")
            }

            ForEach(self.buildings, id: \.self) { building in
                if(!self.showFavoritesOnly || building.favourite) {
                    Text("Blah")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I getting a 'Unable to infer complex closure return type; add explicit type to disambiguate' error.

How can I select an item conditionally in a ForEach element?

Comment: May be `ForEach` is asking for the `else` part as it can not return a nil `View` if condition does not match. Just a suggestion I am not sure!

Answer (score 2):

Using a filter is a working solution

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Toggle(isOn: $showFavoritesOnly) {
                Text("Favorites only")
            }

            ForEach(self.buildings.filter({b in self.showFavoritesOnly || b.favourite}), id: \.self) { building in
                Text("Blah")
            }
        }
    }
```

Still, I wonder how could I have fixed it using an if-statement

Comment: I remember that I have seen the “if” approach in an example from Apple. Of course filtering is much better or even better placing it in a View-Model.